# PostgreSQL: add value of one row to another and drop the former

Tags: postgresql

through some obscure error (probably on my side) over the change of the year I've got values "2011-52" in my table (listing virtual money won by players in a week), which actually belong under "2011-01":

```
# select * from pref_money where id='OK324712148886';
       id       | money |   yw
----------------+-------+---------
 OK324712148886 |   203 | 2010-46
 OK324712148886 |   219 | 2010-49
 OK324712148886 |   115 | 2010-51
 OK324712148886 |    63 | 2011-52
 OK324712148886 |    20 | 2011-01
```

To fix that I would like to add the value (63) from the row with the yw='2011-52' to the value (20) of the row with the yw='2011-01' and then drop the former row, for each id in the table.

So I am trying (using PostgreSQL 8.4.6 / CentOS 5.5):

```
# update pref_money set money=money+
    (select money from pref_money where yw='2011-52') 
    where yw='2011-01';
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

this is probably because I need to specify the **id** too inside the round brackets of the subquery? How can I fix my query please?

Thank you! Alex

**UPDATE 2:**

I've also tried:

```
# update pref_money set money=money+
(select money from pref_money m2 where m2.yw='2011-52' and id=m2.id) 
where yw='2011-01';
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

and

```
# update pref_money m1 set m1.money=m1.money+
(select money from pref_money m2 where m2.yw='2011-52' and m1.id=m2.id) 
where m1.yw='2011-01';
ERROR:  column "m1" of relation "pref_money" does not exist
LINE 1: update pref_money m1 set m1.money=m1.money+(select money fro...
```

and:

```
# update pref_money as m1 set money=money+
(select coalesce(money,0) from pref_money as m2 
where m1.id=m2.id and m2.yw='2011-52') 
where m1.yw='2011-01';
ERROR:  null value in column "money" violates not-null constraint
```

And my table definition is:

```
# \d pref_money
                        Table "public.pref_money"
 Column |         Type          |                Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id     | character varying(32) |
 money  | integer               | not null
 yw     | character(7)          | default to_char(now(), 'YYYY-IW'::text)
Indexes:
    "pref_money_yw_index" btree (yw)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "pref_money_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES pref_users(id)
```

And of course I have thousands of rows with different id's or I'd just fix 1 value by hand and wouldn't ask here a question at Stackoverflow.

And I don't agree with the comment, that 2011-52 could be a correct value at the beginning of the year 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing:

```
# update pref_money as m1 set money=money+
      coalesce((select money from pref_money as m2 
      where m1.id=m2.id and m2.yw='2011-52'),0) 
      where m1.yw='2010-52';
UPDATE 2081

# delete from pref_money where yw='2011-52';
DELETE 1223
```

And I should have used **IYYY-IW** instead of YYYY-IW in the 1st place - got both hints from pgsql-general@postgresql.org mailing list

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the subquery returns exactly one row (as the error message suggests). Your sample data doesn't show this, but apparently there is more than one row with *yw='2011-01'* in your table.

If the `id` column is the primary key (or part of it), then yes adding that to the inner select will rectify this problem.

```
update pref_money 
  set money=money +
       (select money 
          from pref_money m2 
         where m2.yw = '2011-52'
           and m2.id = pref_money.id)
where yw='2011-01';
```

Comment: Do you mean m2.id = m1.id? And what if there is no money for 2011-52 for some user id in the table? Do I need to add coalesce() in the subquery?

Comment: I get the error:  update pref_money m1 set m1.money=m1.money+(select money from pref_money m2 where m2.yw='2011-52' and m1.id=m2.id) where m1.yw='2011-01';
ERROR:  column "m1" of relation "pref_money" does not exist
LINE 1: update pref_money m1 set m1.money=m1.money+(select money fro...

Comment: You cannot use an alias for the table being updated. I fixed the typo in my example

Answer (score 0):

Well, this 52 is maybe not really an error. The first week of this 201 year is really numbered 52 in ISO year. Sometimes it's 0, sometimes it's 52. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date.

So maybe you do not want the ISO number of the week, as it can be a problem when doing order by queries, maybe. Or try to change 2011-52 to 2010-52.

And do not merge 2011-52 and 2011-01, 2011-01 start on 03/01/2011. 01/01/2011 & 02/01/2011 are really in week 52 !

Comment: Yes I'm using ISO week number and have updated my question to show this. But are you sure a week numbered 52 can occur at the beginning of the year 2011? And also I've restarted my scripts and now the yw of 2011-01 is used (maybe I was using non-ISO week numbers before and forgotten to update production scripts), so I need to merge my values.

Comment: I'm sure 52 can exists for a starting week, I've got my 2011 calendar in front of me and the first 2 days are in week 52, and today it's 1, there were no 0 this year :-) . Read the wikipedia link, I'm not lying.

Comment: Yes, 2011-01-01 and 2011-01-02 are in week 52, but they are in week 52 of 2010, so the correct specification would be 2010-52.

Comment: Ok, then I need to add those 2 days to 2010-52 and drop 2011-52 (where they are currently for whatever reason). So I still need an answer to my original question about not-working SQL UPDATE command...

Comment: That's why I stated the fix should be "Or try to change 2011-52 to 2010-52".

Comment: Ok, but I still need to add the money values (add 2011-52 to 2010-52) somehow and I can't figure out the SQL command for that.

Comment: maybe you can write a simple PHP script with some foreach loops to make all the queries needed in a 'keep it stupid simple' way, one shot, then remove the file, and avoid breaking your datas with a complex SQL update query?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities would be to use an aggregate and do something like:

```
  update pref_money as pm 
     set money = money+money_delta
    from ( select id, sum(money) as money_delta 
             from pref_money as pmt 
            where yw > '2011-01' -- here you should include only the records, that are really corrupted
                                 -- for the example of the data from you, text > should work
            group by id) as pmd
   where pm.id = pmd.id;
     and pm.yw = '2010-01';
```

But to say the truth, I would use a `date` data type for the `yw` field and set a constraint `date_trunc('month', yw)::date = yw` to ensure the date in `yw` is only the first day of the month.

Comment: oh, if it is the year week, then ignore the comment about the month :)

Comment: Hello, unfortunately can't get your solution to work (even if I omit the superfluous semicolon in the middle) - it tells me UPDATE 0